# C# Flow Diagram of Objects

Tags: c#, .net, graph

I have objects that look more or less as follows:

```
public class Object1
{
   public string connectionIn1 { get; set; }
   public string connectionIn2 { get; set; }
   public string connectionIn3 { get; set; }

   public string connectionOut1 { get; set; }
   public string connectionOut2 { get; set; }
   public string connectionOut3 { get; set; }

   public dynamic property1 { get; set; }
   public dynamic property2 { get; set; }
   public dynamic property3 { get; set; }

}
```

Objects are connected to each other via the `connectionIn` and `connectionOut` property.  What I need to do is let the user use a flowchart environment to place the objects on the flowsheet, and connect them.  is there any flowcharting library for .NET that will allow me to place objects on a flowsheet, and set properties to the specific object on the flow sheet and connect the objects?

I would like to keep this application open source so a commercial solution is not an option for me...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified that, but if you're using WPF, please take a look at [Graph#](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/). I've been using it for a while myself and it's not too bad at all.